# How to create web service receive point to call outbound service using SoapUI 5.3.0 tool?

Tags: web-services, testing, wsdl, soapui, outbound

I start my testing job with **inbound services**. Everything was fine, I call created WSDL, put parameters in request and recieve SoapUI WS respond.

Now I need to test also **outbound service**, but to this job, I need to create  system or point which recieve this message.

Is it possible with SoapUI tool? How to do that?

Can anyone help me? I`m new one with testing outbound services.

Comment: Madara, What do you mean by `outbound service`? Assuming that you are using `soapui` tool as client (testing) to call the existing services running some where. What is your use case?

Comment: Yes, the purpose ar this test case is to call existing services (system authomatic e-mail sending and notification from system to users). I need to test if made web services work correct, but I can`t find a way how to create receiving point with SoapUI.

Comment: You mean to say that you want test if you are recieving email or not from soapui?

Comment: Yes, if (and what kind of) e-mails and notifications I receive at special my defined conditions.

Comment: SoapUI is not really suitable(IMO) for such kind of test though you could write some groovy code.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Is it possible to contact in any private way? I need help with SoapUI and I need some help. Of course, if you have some free time.

Comment: Can you join here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157916/soapui